# How to convert string to double in C#

Tags: c#, recommendation-engine

In the following code , rating in generating error

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Ratings.csv");

var parsed = from line in allLines
            let row = line.Split(';')
             select new
             {
                 UserId = row[0],
                 ItemId = row[1],
                 rating = row[3]
            };
var Rating = parsed.Select(x => new AddRating (x.UserId, x.ItemId,x.rating));

client.Send(new Batch(Rating));


var detailViews = parsed.Select(x => new AddDetailView(x.UserId, x.ItemId,x.rating ));
```

Comment: Recombee is used in this example

Comment: Which line is throwing which exception? Details details details please.

Comment: `double.Parse(rating)` or `TryParse()`

Comment: Have a look at `double.TryParse(string, out double)`

Comment: x.rating giving exception ( cannot convert form string to double)

Comment: Is your ```AddRating``` constructor expecing a double?

Comment: yes its expecting double

Comment: `rating = double.Parse(row[3])` though `TryParse` is better for error handling

Comment: Matt , thanks problem is solved,

Comment: All other members thats for input

Comment: After doing rating = double.Parse(row[3])                                                           I am getting this error                                                                             System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: Are you sure it's `row[3]` not `row[2]`, if it is `3` then you'll have to check the size of `row` before trying to call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is telling you what the issue is. Your constructor is expecting doubles, and you're passing it strings. In order to fix it, you've gotta parse your string inputs into doubles.

The way your code is written, you'll have to change the way you're using the `.Select` statement in order to parse it in a decent error handling manner.

I'd suggest swapping the `.Select` for a `foreach`, then parsing each property, then instantiating your class.

```
foreach (var item in parsed)
{
    double userId = 0;
    double itemId = 0;
    double rating = 0;
    double.TryParse(item.UserId, out userId);
    double.TryParse(item.ItemId, out itemId);
    double.TryParse(item.rating, out rating);

    var rating = new AddRating(userId, itemId, rating);
    //**** do whatever you want with the new object
}
```

Comment: Thanks James for input

Comment: You can now simplify each statement to `double.TryParse(item.UserId, out double userId);` without the need to declare `userId` beforehand.

Comment: @ja72 Woah. Learn something new every day! Has this been available for a while?

Comment: It was added recently in one of the `C#` `7.x` updates.

Answer (score 0):

```
String st = "85.78";
Double db = Convert.ToDouble(st);

//Or With Error Hndler

try
        {
            string st = "85.78";
            Double db = Convert.ToDouble(st);
        }
catch (FormatException)
        {

            // Your error handler 

        }
```

Comment: Thanks Hayk for input

Comment: The only downside to this is that if the op doesn't wrap it in a ```try/catch```, it will throw an exception if the input can't be converted.

Comment: It's not such a problem to add try/catch  and throw exceptions.